# How to assign numbers to letters for anagram search using modified Rabin-Karp

Tags: algorithm, anagram, rabin-karp

I have to assign numbers to letters a,b,c,d...z such that for a given string and all anagram search we can do it in o(n) using hash search. The hash function is supposedly s[0]+s[1]+s[2]..s[n-1]. Anagram is positional independent so there is no need to multiply with positional powers as in Rabin-Karp.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i read normal rabin karp &  it feels using prime numbers  like   3   5  7    11   13   17   19   31     might be the key but i am not able to prove its the right thing .    my small cases i wrote passed but that doesnt prove its authenticity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose some convenient prime modulus p (maybe 2<sup>31</sup> − 1) and then map each letter to a random number between 0 and p−1 inclusive. It can be shown that, assuming every word has fewer than p of each letter, the probability of a spurious collision between two words is 1/p.

Comment: how to show that sir ? So you are saying that assigning prime or non-prime  integer to an alphabet  has no impact from probability standpoint  ?

Comment: @MAG For any number c between 1 and p-1 inclusive, the function f(x) = cx mod p is a one-to-one map on the integers between 0 and p-1 inclusive. Given two distinct words, they have different counts of at least one letter, and this implies that the contribution of this letter to the hash is enough to ensure that the difference of hashes is uniformly distributed in 0..p-1.